# Recovering package metadata info

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, metadata, info

From the console, is there a way to recover the architecture of a package when it is not currently installed ? I know the name and version of the package.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean getting the information for a package, you can only obtain it if is still available from the APT cache, to get it from a terminal run:

```
apt-cache show packagename
```

To only show the architecture use grep

```
apt-cache show package_name | grep Architecture

# Or for the lazy typist
apt-cache show package_name | grep Arch
```

Answer (score -1):

Apart that usually the name of a package includes also its architecture, e.g. in
tar_1.23-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb you see that is for x86_64 (amd64),
anyway you use use the command "dpkg --info ".
Among various fields, there is also Architecture. E.g.

```
$ dpkg --info tar_1.23-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb | grep Architecture  
Architecture: amd64
```

Comment: That will not work if the package is not installed as the OP is asking.